# nuget Typescript is only compiling a single file

Tags: typescript, visual-studio

I'm really at a loss for this. This should be simple but for whatever reason it just isn't working. I'm building an ASP.NET web app in VS 2022 and I have the nuget Typescript package. For the typescript frontend I'm building I have the classes and functionality spread across several files, all within subdirectories of the main TS file and tsconfig.json. The IDE has no problem finding classes, interfaces, etc. in the subfolders, but then when the Typescript is transpiled into JS it only does the main file and nothing else. I've tried putting manual includes in the tsconfig.json, but inexplicably this makes VS throw errors that it can't find the references class or whatever. Very frustrating.

My barebones tsconfig is below

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "noEmitOnError": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "target": "esNext",
    "outDir": "../../wwwroot/js"
  },
  "compileOnSave": true,

  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "wwwroot"
  ]
}
```

I've also tried without compileOnSave but it makes no difference.
Why isn't it bundling everything into a single JS file? From what I understand that's what it's supposed to do...

Answer (score 0):

well that was easier than it should've been. I swapped out the outDir param for outFile and it worked. Weirdly the TS compiler wasn't building different files for the other project files, which seems wrong.